# Laravel 4 Get HTTP Basic Authentication Credentials

Tags: php, laravel

I need to make a custom basic.auth filter as this one doesn't fit my requirements, how can I get the credentials for a HTTP Basic Authentication request?

```
Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic('username');
});


Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    $username = request->http_username...
});
```

Comment: Use a proper framework to start with. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html 
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.http.html

Comment: @Anyone Haters gunna hate.